# How can a Javascript parent window send data to popup window?

Tags: javascript, popup

I have been writing a browser based application (or rather, rapid prototyping an application) using HTML and Javascript.  I would like the main window to be able to display popup windows with dynamic data. However, I cannot figure out how to push data from a parent window to a popup window in Javascript. Note, I am working with the assumption that the application may be used in "offline" scenarios, so all dynamic data should be coming from the main window.

Ideally, I'd like to write

```
var popup = window.open("popup.html", someidentifier, "");
popup.document.getElementById("SomeIdInPopupHtml").innerHTML = "1,2,3,4";
```

However, the getElementById function returns NULL.  How can I push data to popup windows from a parent window?

Comment: I know this might be a silly question, but are you positive that the child window has a node with that ID? Remember, case does matter!

Comment: is the `var popup` within scope of the other function that is calling it?  the syntax you have is correct.

Comment: @Steven Paligo, yes, the popup.html (in this example) has a well defined "data" element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the popup serving content from a different domain than the parent? If so, the short answer is you can't.

The long answer is that you can sent the popup's href fragment (i.e. the part after the # in protocol://server/path?query#fragment). If the content in the popup knows to check its fragment for changes, then you can pass data to it.

If it's from the same domain then your code should work, as long as an element with that id exists.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think I may be able to work with this idea.

Answer (score 1):

> However, the getElementById function returns NULL.

Because `popup.html` hasn't loaded yet. If you want to interact with content from the document, you'll have to call back later when it has finished loading.

For completely dynamic popups, `open` them with a blank URL and `popupwindow.document.write` their content into them. For co-operatively-scripting popups loaded from a separate document, have the child document call its parent when it is ready to be accessed. Or just use in-page pop-up divs which are typically less annoyance, both for you as a coder and for the end user.

Comment: Thanks! Can you suggest a good way to call back later that will ensure the page has finished loading? I tried jQuery's $(popup.document).ready(...), but it did not seem to work for me.

Comment: Also, for document.writing... this was my initial approach, however I found myself writing JS that wrote JS. It wasn't very pretty, and it felt wrong.

Comment: @Willi: The problem with `$(something in another document)` is that jQuery doesn't really support cross-document scripting: some things work, others that are coded to rely on the particular `document` object the jQuery is associated with (like `ready`, but also many more) don't. You generally have to have a separate copy of jQuery in each document. `document.write()` is a nasty hack but reasonable for simple documents. Otherwise, include a hook to have the child call its parent back on ready.

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks on your link to open the popup window pass a query string to it and then react to that value with your server side code.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however I may have multiple popups, each with different information. For example, a different popup window content for each player in the NBA, although the popup.html template source would be the same.  How can I pass the identifier to the popup?

Comment: @Willi Ballenthin, I understand that you may have different data, I will update my answer so that it is a little more obvious.

Comment: unfortunately, having the server react doesn't answer the question: "Note, I am working with the assumption that the application may be used in "offline" scenarios, so all dynamic data should be coming from the main window."

Comment: @Willi Ballenthin, the previously posted code can call functions in the parent window and run them in the parent window only. I don't believe you can pass data to the child window. You say that the app might be used offline, why not store all of the possible details in the child window. When the user clicks in the parent window it passes a query string, then get the query string and show the correct details.

Comment: Or you can just use your own popup window with a div?

Answer (score 0):

Let me start off by presenting a possible solution that I just experimented with. I would like to encourage feedback and better solutions, however...

Its not very neat, but I can append GET-style query parameters to the source URL of the popup:

```
var popup = window.open("popup.html?" + identifier, somename, "");
```

Now in my particular situation, the popup is a view to some model identified by a unique ID, so the popup window can ask for the parent window for data related to that ID:

```
var model = window.opener.getModel(document.location.href.split("?")[1]);
do_something_with_model(model);
```

This strategy won't work in all cases, especially when the data is not easily marshaled into the `getModel()` implementation. However, in my case, I think this approach may work.

I'd appreciate feedback on this strategy.  Thanks!