# How to pass data from Parent html window to pop-up window

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I am trying to pass some data from parent window to pop up window in html.

Below is my code-

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function init()
{
    popupWin = window.open('','popupWin','');
    popupWin.document.writeln('<html><head><title>test</title></head><body><form><input type="text" id="popupTextBox"/></form></body></html>');
    popupWin.document.close();
    popupText = popupWin.document.getElementById("popupTextBox");
    parentText = document.getElementById("parentTextBox");
}
function transferText()
{
    popupText.value = parentText.value
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="parentTextBox"/>
<input type="button" onclick="init();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

But somehow I am not able to pass that textbox data to popup window with the above code. Is there any problem with this?

In general, I am trying to pass some data from parent window to popup window.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187510/how-can-a-javascript-parent-window-send-data-to-popup-window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to call `transferText()`
After calling `transferText()` the text was transferred...

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function init()
{
    popupWin = window.open('','popupWin','');
    popupWin.document.writeln('<html><head><title>test</title></head><body><form><input type="text" id="popupTextBox"/></form></body></html>');
    popupWin.document.close();
    popupText = popupWin.document.getElementById("popupTextBox");
    parentText = document.getElementById("parentTextBox");
    transferText();
}
function transferText()
{
    popupText.value = parentText.value
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="parentTextBox"/>
<input type="button" onclick="init();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what should be the actual flow of calling the methods? can you provide the full syntax code for that. Thanks

Comment: Is there any way to do the opposite? Pass data from the popup to the parent window?